# Encrypting User Data in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm currently working on a cross platform game and I need to store some user data. Initially scores etc but later probably details about in app purchases. I started looking at CCUserData but of course this kind of data needs encryption so it wasn't really suitable.

Any suggestions on what path to go down? If it comes to it I guess will just store it as an xml file that I encrypt myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not a special encryption way in cocos2d-x but you can read about data encryption on Internet. there is a book that may help you. it introduced some simple encryption methods and their breaking ways. download [here](http://inventwithpython.com/HackingSecretCiphersWithPython.pdf)